How to set the same width to the ttk.Combobox and ttk.Entry widgets?
I have to put three widgets (ttk.Combobox, ttk.Entry and ttk.Combobox) in series with the same width. Below an example:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def configure_column_widths(frame, num_columns):
    for i in range(num_columns):
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tkinter Example")

main_frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10")
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E, tk.N, tk.S))

configure_column_widths(main_frame, 3)

combobox1 = ttk.Combobox(main_frame)
combobox1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E))

entry = ttk.Entry(main_frame)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E))

combobox2 = ttk.Combobox(main_frame)
combobox2.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E))

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()

The ttk.Entry one doesn't have the same width than the other ones. How can I fix this issue?


From the description for grid_columnconfigure() in tkdoc:

The -weight option (an integer value) sets the relative weight for apportioning any extra spaces among columns. A weight of zero (0) indicates the column will not deviate from its requested size. A column whose weight is two will grow at twice the rate as a column of weight one when extra space is allocated to the layout. The -uniform option, when a non-empty value is supplied, places the column in a uniform group with other columns that have the same value for -uniform. The space for columns belonging to a uniform group is allocated so that their sizes are always in strict proportion to their -weight values.

Setting weight=1 does not guarantee that those columns having same width, you need to set both weight and uniform to having same values for those columns in order to make them having same width:
def configure_column_widths(frame, num_columns):
    # columns with same value of "uniform" options will have
    # same width if weight=1 is set as well
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(list(range(num_columns)), weight=1, uniform='a')

Output:

